# CSS Styled Button double colour

Tags: html, css

My button looks like this (atachement) and my CSS Code for the Button looks like that and it is double colored. How can I change it that it is just light green:

```
.button {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    border-color: hsl(126, 100%, 30%);
    border-radius: 1.5em/50%;

}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guRTU.png)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Oops I forgot it but i did it now

Answer (score 0):

the **border-style** has to be defined which is defined as **solid** in the below code, if it is not defined it will have to use **inset** border-style as the border-style which is the default

```
 .button {
       font-size: 1rem;
       font-weight: bold;
       padding: 1em 2em;
       cursor: pointer;
       background: transparent;
       color: white;
       border: solid 1px hsl(126, 100%, 30%);
       border-radius: 1.5em/50%;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set your border's "style" to `solid`, right now it is set to `inset`. Add `border-style: solid` to your CSS:

```
.button {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    border-color: hsl(126, 100%, 30%);
    border-radius: 1.5em/50%;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

If you want to revert the changes either remove `border-style: solid;` or use `border-style: inset;`

More on [border-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi:Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable